IDEA httpClient upload multiple files，gin error: malformed MIME header: missing colon
this is my http file code:
# curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/api/v1/file/upload  -F "file=upload_file_1.txt"  -F "file=upload_file_2.txt"
// @no-log
POST http://localhost:8000/api/v1/file/upload
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=boundary


--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="upload_file_1.txt"


< upload_file_1.txt
--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="upload_file_2.txt"


< upload_file_2.txt
--boundary--

this is my gin server code, handle upload file func :
func FileUpload(ctx *gin.Context)  {
    if form, err := ctx.MultipartForm(); err == nil {
        files := form.File["file"]
        fmt.Println(len(files))
        for _, file := range files {
            fmt.Println("Uploaded file:", file.Filename)
        }
    } else {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    ctx.JSON(http.StatusOK,common.Success.WithMsg("upload file"))
}

But when I run the http code, my GIN program prints:
[GIN-debug] Listening and serving HTTP on :8000
malformed MIME header: missing colon: "--73ad88c960d815cb"
[GIN] 2024/12/04 - 09:47:03 | 200 |      11.306ms |       127.0.0.1 | POST     "/api/v1/file/upload"

When I use HTML, I get the file I uploaded correctly:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="http://localhost:8000/api/v1/file/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" multiple/>
    <input type="submit" value="提交"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>

Here's the correct output log when I upload a file using html, I'd like to see the output correct when using httpclient requests
2
Uploaded file: upload_file_1.txt
Uploaded file: upload_file_2.txt
[GIN] 2024/12/04 - 09:50:16 | 200 |      41.269ms |             ::1 | POST     "/api/v1/file/upload"

